# How to make an oracle cursor continue after it fetches a failed row?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Executing the following PL/SQL block:

```
declare
   cursor c1 is
      select rownum r1,
      5/
      case when r = 5 then 0 else 1 end
      dzero, r from
      (
      SELECT RowNum r FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 10
      ) 
      ;
BEGIN

  dbms_output.enable(buffer_size => NULL);

  begin
     FOR c1_rec in c1
     LOOP
          dbms_output.put_line('val: ' || c1_rec.r1);
     END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error: '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
  end;

END;
```

Output is:

```
val: 1
val: 2
val: 3
val: 4
Error: -1476 -ERROR- ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
```

Given that the query of c1 unchanged, how to make the cursor continue to fetch the 6-10th rows, so that the output continue to show the followings?

```
val: 6
val: 7
val: 8
val: 9
val: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there's no way of catching that exception. The right thing to do would be to use `NULLIF` to avoid the division by zero but you would have to change the query:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT rownum r1,
           5/NULLIF(CASE WHEN r = 5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 0) dzero, 
           r 
    FROM (SELECT RowNum r FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 10) ;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.enable(buffer_size => NULL);

  FOR c1_rec in c1 LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('val: ' || c1_rec.r1);
  END LOOP;
END;
```